# Value of type UIImage has to value bindTo

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift2, xcode7

Am trying to build a photo sharing app in Swift 2.0, I've used carthage to bring SWIFTBOND in my xcode project but unfortunately am having this problem.

[image]

```
var post: Post? {

    didSet {

        // 1

        if let post = post {

            //2

            //bind the image of the post to the `postImage` view

            var image: Observable<UIImage?> = Observable(nil)

            post.image.bindTo(postImageView.bnd_image) //here its getting me an error

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati: Please stop adding [noise like "Thanks"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually using the `image` of type `Observable<UIImage?>`.  Instead, you are mistakenly trying to bind the `image` on `post`.

To fix the compilation error, change the binding to:

```
var image: Observable<UIImage?> = Observable(nil)
image.bindTo(postImageView.bnd_image)
```

To truly fix your code, I would need to see how `image` is defined on the `Post` class.  I'm guessing it is of type `UIImage` which is wrong, it should be of type `Observable<UIImage?>`

eg, this would be wrong:

```
class Post {
    var image:UIImage? = nil
}
```

and instead should be:

```
class Post {
    var image:Observable<UIImage?> = Observable(nil)
}
```

BTW, I love Bond. :]